# jetty:run-forked not scanning for changed classes - hot swap is not working

Tags: java, maven, maven-jetty-plugin

I am using the maven jetty plugin and am having issues getting hot swap to work.  When I change a class and compile through maven, the change is not being picked up.

I am using the scanIntervalSeconds setting, but it looks like it is being ignored.

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
  <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <configuration>
  <jettyXml>src/main/resources/jetty/jetty-env.xml</jettyXml>
  <jvmArgs>-Xms512m -Xmx2048m -Denv.name=qa -Xdebug -Xnoagent -Djava.compiler=NONE -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=9191</jvmArgs>
  <stopPort>9999</stopPort>
  <stopKey>foo</stopKey>
  <useProvidedScope>true</useProvidedScope>
  <scanIntervalSeconds>5</scanIntervalSeconds>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

I have seen a million examples of this, but I am using jetty:run-forked and not jetty:run.  Could that be the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Dug,

First off, I recommend you upgrade to a newer version of the plugin - I can tell its not the latest because the groupId should be org.eclipse.jetty, not org.mortbay.jetty. The latest release is 9.1.0.v20131115.

That motherhood statement aside, the run-forked goal isn't currently designed to do automatic hot redeploys. If that's a feature you'd like to see, then please go ahead and open a bugzilla for it over on the jetty issue tracker: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/enter_bug.cgi?product=Jetty

cheers
Jan